# How do I get the max bonus money for the cases

Tags: another-case-solved

At the bottom left hand corner of each case is a max bonus dollar amount. How do I get that money?? It always seems to be ten times what the case actually pays does anyone have a good suggestion? I seem to spend all of my money on tools and I need some furniture lol

Answer (score 1):

I'm also on my way to find out how to reach the max bonus.

Here are some ways I find out myself:

1. Improve your skills
   There are many helpful skills. My favorit is the "All next tiles are of the chosen tile" and "Switch two tiles". The skills are helpful because you don't habe to spend money for using. You are also able to upgrade skills to have more uses in every case or to have less tile cost per use. (cost for upgrade 1 star and 50 candy).
   You will be able to collect more tiles for less cost.
2. Tiles and evidence equal money
   For every unused tile or evidence you will get money at the end of the case. Try to get more tiles and evidence than needed for the case. Skills and tools are very helpful. You have to pay attention, that you don't use them too often. Skills cost (sometimes) tiles or evidence and tools cost money. At the end of the case there is the possibility, that you spend more money then earned. (I made the experience -_-' )
3. Use skills and tools
   To get the best tools, you have to buy furniture. To buy furniture you need more money... I see your dilemma. In my opinion, one of the best tools are "All next tiles are XY" (cost 50 money). It speed up the game. You will have more moves to collect more tiles and evidence than needed. Again: don't over spend.
4. Use your intuition
   Sometimes there are hints inside the story such as "the blonde girl". If you are searching for a person, you can discard every other hair color without paying an photo. The same for the map. If you are searching for a golf course, you have to look for green lawen. This saves tiles and evidence.

Summon:
Before starting the case improve your skills
Try to get as many tiles and evidence as possible
Use helpful tools and skills without an overspand
Read the story and use your intuition

btw: the value for an unused tile is 1 money. If you do the newspaper: the value of a coin is 2 money.

Comment: THis is not an actual answer, this is just guessing and opinion work

Answer (score 1):

My trick to get lots of money, but it only works if you have the 3rd or 4th filing cabinet is to overuse the "All next clues are of type" tools combined with "Pickup all clues of type". For example, the tools i use the most are :

- Coffee & Police Cap
- Gloves & Thief Cap
- Notepad & Fedora Hat
- Foot Cast & Runner Band
- Fingerprint Set & Deerstalker

Also, having the 3rd level and 4th level lamps help a lot making more money since you will have a higher tool limit. I have 4 of each right now and i think the Posh Lamp (4th level) adds another one but i'm not sure.

So how to do this? Start a case, even the simplest cases can work, just donc take the first few ones where you don't have all the clue types, take at least the 5th one from the 1st chapter. Don't try this on daily cases, the bonus at the end is only x2 and it will not be worth it, only try this with real cases.

1. Do the puzzle portion until you have only a few moves left
2. Gather all evidence to maximize your clue spaces, using the pins or binoculars are particularly helpful in this case
3. Use a Police Cap to change all clues to donuts, then the fingerprint set to pick up all magnifiers. Most of your clues should now be Donuts.
4. Use a thief cap to change all clues to lockpicks and use a Coffee, this will change most of your clues to lockpics
5. Use a Fedora Hat and then a glove, this will change all lockpicks (a hefty bunch of them at this point) into questions
6. Use a runner band and then a notepad, now, technically, if you done it right, all clues should be footprints except for 1 candy.
7. Just go on and follow the chain and repeat until you have completed the usage of all your tools.
8. Profit

I just finished the "Marzipan murder", it is case #8 or #9 in the 3rd chapter and got 4800$'ish reward because i had 4th cabinet, 4th dresser and 3rd lamp and i collected something like 800 clues or so.

Once this is done, just go to the store and buy anew those tools you used... it'll cost you between 600$ and 1000$ depending on your lamp level (In my case 800$ = 8 tools x 4 units x 25$) but considering i made 4800$ it's worth my while as i would not have gotten that much money yet.

Another advantage to this is that gathering so many clues allows you to get at least 3-4 candies from the trucks which is not extraordinary, but 4 candies is always welcome!

Comment: is there no way to get the max bonus for replayed cases? I just tried the "chain" method from Matthieu above, but it didn't give me any coins for clues collected :(

Answer (score 0):

to get the max bonus of a major case you have to collect clues , the number of all clues in total multiplied by 2 equals the max bonus . 
example : max bonus of a case is 6000 , then you have to get 3000 clues in total .
it worked and got the achievement .

Answer (score 0):

You can save more evidence by the following method: 
 In a city search for instance, use the binoculars to uncover all hidden icons (You may have to use candies for this). Use maps for hints. When you find the place, close the application without answering the question. Open it again and continue the case. Click the place without using any of your items.

The same can be done for the person search and the room search. This also helps when you accidentally choose the wrong place / person and are about to fail the case. Just exit the application immediately without proceeding and reopen it. You get another chance to do the task.

Answer (score 0):

In the city map, when if you use clues to find the place, you can exit the game and log on again without losing the case but the city will reset.
In conclusion use all you got find the place, log off and on again, and point the place

Answer (score -1):

At the end of the game you have to have collect more than 250 of every clue.

Comment: please can you provide proof of this

Comment: This is wrong, i've had many times way more than 250 of each clues by abusing the tool chain i explained and you won't get the achievement with just that!